# Provisioning vagrant vm with Chef, and multiple users - how to handle the *.pem files?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I have a project repo that I want to setup with Vagrant for our software team. I have a chef server, I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding how to write the `VagrantFile` in order to make it usable by multiple members of the software team...

Scenario 1: Each user has a user set up on the chef-server...

so in the `VagrantFile`..

```
config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
  chef.chef_server_url = "https://my-chef-server/"

  # best way to set this? pass it in as a variable? set it as an ENV variable?
  chef.validation_client_name = "users-name"   
  # users can have their .pem files on their local machine...
  chef.validation_key_path = "~/.chef/users-name.pem
end
```

Scenario 2: use the same username for each project...

```
config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
  chef.chef_server_url = "https://my-chef-server/"
  chef.validation_client_name = "the-project-name"

  # would this need to be committed to the project repo then?
  chef.validation_key_path = ".chef/users-name.pem
end
```

I've also read about knife.rb files, but it sounds like they get committed into the repo, and that seems like a very strange way to go about things. A) that still doesn't support multiple users and B) is it secure to have these validation keys in the repo? The fact that I can't find much on google about this also leads me to believe that I might be missing something obvious so any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You may end with as many answer as there's users of vagrant and chef ... Personnaly I do use env vars in the vagrantfile for this kind of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1

Use test-kitchen.  I know it's called TEST-kitchen, but you don't need tests to use it.  It will use your local knife.rb file automatically for you, so no need to put secrets anywhere like a repo.  Added bonus, you can use any of the kitchen plugins to launch into cloud providers, docker, etc.  I know Vagrant supports many of those options too, but I feel that kitchen makes it a bit cleaner and easier.

## Option 2

Put your user and key_path into environment variables, and reference those in your Vagrantfile.

Comment: the local `knife.rb` file lives in `~/.chef/knife.rb` by default right? That's where I imagine test-kitchen looks for it anyway? So perhaps I could just read that file in at the start of the `VagrantFile` and use the values within.

Comment: I think I've been mistunderstanding... the clients all checkout the chef-repo locally, and provisioned VM's use their local chef-repo rather than pointing at it directly on github or similar. That makes a bit more sense now!